# The same packages are installed in two architecture versions

Tags: debian, apt, multiarch

I’m using a i386/amd64 multiarch on my freshly installed debian 8.7 . I just added it through `dpkg --add-architecture i386` to install a package I couldn’t find in a amd64 version.

Then I installed the jessie-backports (375) version of my nvidia driver using the repository :

```
# jessie-backports
deb http://httpredir.debian.org/debian jessie-backports main contrib non-free
```

and this is what synaptic is giving me now :

[image: Synaptic]

I got all these nvidia packages installed twice, one for each architecture. Is this anything normal? Did I do something wrong during all this process ?

The really weird thing is that `apt list --installed |grep nvidia` is not even giving me the same answer :

```
ut@Albizia:~$ apt list --installed |grep nvidia

WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface yet. Use with caution in scripts.

glx-alternative-nvidia/jessie-backports,now 0.7.3~bpo8+1 amd64  [installé, automatique]
libegl-nvidia0/jessie-backports,now 375.26-1~bpo8+1 amd64  [installé, automatique]
libegl1-glvnd-nvidia/jessie-backports,now 375.26-1~bpo8+1 amd64  [installé, automatique]
libgl1-glvnd-nvidia-glx/jessie-backports,now 375.26-1~bpo8+1 amd64  [installé, automatique]
libgl1-nvidia-glvnd-glx/jessie-backports,now 375.26-1~bpo8+1 amd64  [installé, automatique]
libgldispatch0-nvidia/jessie-backports,now 375.26-1~bpo8+1 amd64  [installé, automatique]
libgles-nvidia1/jessie-backports,now 375.26-1~bpo8+1 amd64  [installé, automatique]
libgles-nvidia2/jessie-backports,now 375.26-1~bpo8+1 amd64  [installé, automatique]
libgles1-glvnd-nvidia/jessie-backports,now 375.26-1~bpo8+1 amd64  [installé, automatique]
libgles2-glvnd-nvidia/jessie-backports,now 375.26-1~bpo8+1 amd64  [installé, automatique]
libglx-nvidia0/jessie-backports,now 375.26-1~bpo8+1 amd64  [installé, automatique]
libglx0-glvnd-nvidia/jessie-backports,now 375.26-1~bpo8+1 amd64  [installé, automatique]
libnvidia-cfg1/jessie-backports,now 375.26-1~bpo8+1 amd64  [installé, automatique]
libnvidia-eglcore/jessie-backports,now 375.26-1~bpo8+1 amd64  [installé, automatique]
libnvidia-glcore/jessie-backports,now 375.26-1~bpo8+1 amd64  [installé, automatique]
libnvidia-ml1/jessie-backports,now 375.26-1~bpo8+1 amd64  [installé, automatique]
libopengl0-glvnd-nvidia/jessie-backports,now 375.26-1~bpo8+1 amd64  [installé, automatique]
nvidia-alternative/jessie-backports,now 375.26-1~bpo8+1 amd64  [installé, automatique]
nvidia-driver/jessie-backports,now 375.26-1~bpo8+1 amd64  [installé, automatique]
nvidia-driver-bin/jessie-backports,now 375.26-1~bpo8+1 amd64  [installé, automatique]
nvidia-driver-libs/jessie-backports,now 375.26-1~bpo8+1 amd64  [installé, automatique]
nvidia-driver-libs-i386/jessie-backports,now 375.26-1~bpo8+1 i386  [installé, automatique]
nvidia-egl-common/jessie-backports,now 375.26-1~bpo8+1 amd64  [installé, automatique]
nvidia-egl-icd/jessie-backports,now 375.26-1~bpo8+1 amd64  [installé, automatique]
nvidia-installer-cleanup/jessie-backports,now 20151021+1~bpo8+1 amd64  [installé, automatique]
nvidia-kernel-common/jessie-backports,now 20151021+1~bpo8+1 amd64  [installé, automatique]
nvidia-kernel-dkms/jessie-backports,now 375.26-1~bpo8+1 amd64  [installé, automatique]
nvidia-kernel-support/jessie-backports,now 375.26-1~bpo8+1 amd64  [installé, automatique]
nvidia-legacy-check/jessie-backports,now 375.26-1~bpo8+1 amd64  [installé, automatique]
nvidia-modprobe/jessie-backports,now 358.09-1~bpo8+1 amd64  [installé, automatique]
nvidia-persistenced/jessie-backports,now 358.09-1~bpo8+1 amd64  [installé, automatique]
nvidia-settings/jessie-backports,now 375.26-3~bpo8+1 amd64  [installé, automatique]
nvidia-support/jessie-backports,now 20151021+1~bpo8+1 amd64  [installé, automatique]
nvidia-vdpau-driver/jessie-backports,now 375.26-1~bpo8+1 amd64  [installé, automatique]
nvidia-vulkan-common/jessie-backports,now 375.26-1~bpo8+1 amd64  [installé, automatique]
nvidia-vulkan-icd/jessie-backports,now 375.26-1~bpo8+1 amd64  [installé, automatique]
xserver-xorg-video-nvidia/jessie-backports,now 375.26-1~bpo8+1 amd64  [installé]
```

According to this, each package is installed just once. I don’t know whom to trust anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Synaptic is right, you have a number of NVIDIA library packages installed for both `amd64` and `i386`. This is normal: the NVIDIA driver package depends on `nvidia-driver-libs`, which itself recommends `nvidia-driver-libs-i386` which pulls in the `i386` libraries on `amd64` (if you have the `i386` architecture available). That way both `amd64` and `i386` binaries can use the libraries; this comes in handy for example if you want to run 32-bit games.

`apt list` only shows one architecture per installed package, so you'll only see the `amd64` version of packages with both architectures installed.